# Is the expression for CP asymmetry wrong in Wikipedia?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model, electroweak

In the wikipedia page about [neutrino oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Propagation_and_interference) (or ate least in the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Neutrino_oscillation&oldid=807433019)), the CP-asymmetry is written as $$A^{(\alpha\beta)}_{\text{CP}}=P(\nu_\alpha \rightarrow\nu_\beta)-P(\bar{\nu}_{\alpha}\rightarrow\bar{\nu}_{\beta})
    =4\sum_{i>j}\mathrm{Im}\big(U^*_{\alpha i} U_{\beta i}U_{\alpha j} U^*_{\beta j}\big) \sin\Big(\tfrac{\Delta m^2_{ij}L}{2E}\Big)\tag{1}$$ where where $U$ is the neutrino mixing matrix with elements $U_{\alpha i}$. Here, $\alpha$ labels neutrino flavours ($e,\mu$ or $\tau$) and $i$ labels neutrino mass eigenstates such that $$|\nu_\alpha\rangle=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}U^*_{\alpha i}|\nu_i\rangle.$$

Now, the probability of oscillation from neutrino flavour $\alpha$ to flavour $\beta$ is given by$$
\begin{aligned}P_{\alpha\beta}=P(\nu_\alpha \rightarrow\nu_\beta)&=\delta_{\alpha\beta}- 4\sum\limits_{i>j} {\text{Re}}(U_{\alpha i}^{*} U_{\beta i} U_{\alpha j} U_{\beta j}^{*}) \sin^2(\Delta m_{ij}^2 L/4E)\\&+ 
2\sum_{i>j}{\text{Im}}(U_{\alpha i}^{*}U_{\beta i}U_{\alpha j} U_{\beta j}^{*}) \sin(2\Delta m_{ij}^2 L/4E
),\end{aligned}\tag{2}$$
And the probability of oscillation from an antineutrino flavour $\alpha$ to flavour $\beta$ is given by $$
\begin{aligned}P(\bar{\nu}_{\alpha}\rightarrow\bar{\nu}_{\beta})&=P_{\alpha\beta}(U_{\alpha i}\to U^*_{\alpha i})\\&=
\delta_{\alpha\beta}- 4\sum\limits_{i>j} {\text{Re}}(U_{\alpha i} U^*_{\beta i} U^*_{\alpha j} U_{\beta j}) \sin^2(\Delta m_{ij}^2 L/4E)
\\&+ 2\sum_{i>j}{\text{Im}}(U_{\alpha i}U^*_{\beta i}U^*_{\alpha j} U_{\beta j}) \sin(2\Delta m_{ij}^2 L/4E),\end{aligned}\tag{3}.$$  Simple subtraction of (3) from (2), does not lead to Eq. (1). **How is the formula Eq.(1) derived?**

Comment: In WP the formula for (2) given is quite consistent with (1). What makes your think they are not consistent? Are you hiding a bogus discrepancy in your undefined $\Delta_{ij}$? Are you flipping the sign of the imaginary part of the conjugate argument?

Comment: @CosmasZachos
As fas fas the notation $\Delta_{ij}$ is concerned, I have corrected it. I don't understand your other confusions related to the question. I just ask subtracting (3) from (2), does not lead to the expression (1) in the question. This expression is quoted from Wikipedia.

Comment: In eqn (3), the argument of Re and Im is the complex conjugate of the argument of Re and Im in eqn (2), isn't it?

Comment: WP is right. Unless you show your work, (2)-(3) and what confuses you, one cannot figure out your sticking point.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis Oh yes! Thanks . The real parts cancel, and the imaginary parts add up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CP-asymmetry occurs due to phase $\delta$ (I would call this cp-violating phase $\delta$), which makes the elements of mixing matrix complex because of the presence of $e^{-I \delta}$ term. When we deal with anti-neutrinos, the sign of this phase $\delta$ gets changed (as you have done by using the complex conjugation in Eq.(3)). Hence, the $\Re$ part remains the same as is in Eq.(2) but the $\Im$ part obtains the same value as that in Eq.(2) with a (-) sign. This makes Eq.(1) correct, in my opinion.